# google test - how to catch a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, googletest

I know the main code itself should be the one checking pointers.

Currently if/when there's a segmentation fault, the test suites stop running.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to "catch" the segmentation fault in a `TEST_F` like as in a `try-catch` block?

Comment: Note that segmentation faults are not C++ exceptions. They cannot be caught with a `try`/`catch` block. Instead they are signals, that are handled by [signal handlers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal).

Comment: segmentation fault means fix your code, not fix your tests. gtest death test are more like for scenario to verify that application exits if some API is called or some assertion (abort signal) is triggered if API parameter is invalid. Linked duplicate can be a bit misleading for a newbie.